# I'm running into an encoding error trying to use SoX with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sox

This is the error I'm running into:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe FAIL sox: --encoding:
> `ncodedCommand' is not one of: signed-integer, unsigned-integer,
> floating-point, ms-adpcm, ima-adpcm, oki-adpcm, gsm-full-rate, u-law,
> mu-law, a-law.

I've doublechecked the encoding for the wav files and they're correct full resolution wavs (44.1k).  It worked before with a similar bash shell script.

This is the code I'm using.  It's modified from a bash shell script that was used for the same process - to append a wav file to a bunch of other wavs.

```
#Directory for the files that will be looped through and appended
$headerFileDirectory = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\HLDCM030822-uLaw-1-030922\1 wavs"
#Directory for the file to appened the header files with
$appendFileDirectory = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\HLDCM030822-uLaw-1-030922\appendfile"
#Output directory for the combined files to live.
$outputDirectory = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\HLDCM030822-uLaw-1-030922\2 appended wavs"

# Gets the header files
$headers = Get-ChildItem -Path $headerFileDirectory -Filter "*.wav"

# Gets the append file
$appendFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $appendFileDirectory -Filter "append.wav"

# Loop through each header file, and append them with the append file, outputs new files to the output directory.

foreach ($i in $headers)
{
    sox $i $appendFile {$i}out.wav
}
```

Comment: You'll need quotes in your sox command in case your wavs have special chars e.g. 'sox "$($i)" "$($appendFile)" "{$i}out.wav" - also not sure about your last parameter there, did you mean $($i)?. ALSO, if you know where your append file is, you may as well just get it directly: $appendFile = Get-Item "$appendFileDirectory\append.wav"

Comment: Hey!  Sorry if I was a bit confusing, I didn't need any specific special characters in the file names but your help did point me in the right direction.

I added these two parameters to the ps1:

```
 $inputFiles = $i.FullName
 $outputFiles = Join-Path -Path $outputDirectory -ChildPath $i.Name
```

And that solved most of my issues.  BUT I am getting this error now:

Get-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'append.wav'.
+ $appendFile = Get-Item $appendFileDirectory "append.wav"

But despite that error, it seems to work so I think it's solved?

Comment: Sorry I can't tell by how you've written it, you've used ' Get-Item $appendFileDirectory "append.wav" ' in your code? I also derp'd in my suggestion too - you may as well define it directly when you define $appendFileDirectory, there's no need for the multi step. E.g. on line 2 instead of $appendFileDirectory make it "$appendFile= get-item -path "C:\Users\name\Desktop\HLDCM030822-uLaw-1-030922\appendfile\append.wav" - then get rid of line 5 entirely (get-childitem -path $appendFileDirectory -Filter "append.wav")

Comment: Excellent, this removed the error message and works now too!  Thank you so much.